# How to change the store switcher default store selection

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore, stores, switcher

In my application I have 2 store view French and English, I have mentioned French as default one.

[image]

I just wanted to change it as, It should selected french automatically when admin logged in.

I checked it lot and nothing goes right I am not getting where and how I need to change the code.

Help me:)

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1):

So the block information is as follows:

- Template: `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/store/switcher.phtml`
- Block: `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Store/Switcher.php`

But I actually think you need to change your thinking here and maybe set the store that is loaded by default for the product. In this way the store switcher will also default to the correct store.

Comment: I'm also trying to do that (change the store that is loaded), but how do I do that?